# How to start at top of "linked page" with nested React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have nested components using React and React Router. When I click onto a link that swaps out a component, I noticed that it doesn't bring me to the top of the page (for example, if I'm midway down the page, it'll place me there when the new component is loaded in). What's the best way to link to the top of the "next page" (or have it jump there, rather any type of visible scroll when loaded)?  Ideally, with anchor tags or vanilla Javascript (no jQuery). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```